# Unifying auth between a Blazor Server UI and an (effectively external) API

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I've a situation where I'm creating a Blazor Server front end for an API, and that API may also be used directly by some other systems. Essentially some smaller customers might use the UI, others (perhaps larger with their own dev team) build their own UI and use the API. We control both sets of code (for the Blazor and the API).

Auth in the api is done (at the moment) by sending a userid and a password and getting a JWT Bearer token that is added to all subsequent requests.

Auth on the BS app is (at the moment) done using Azure AD B2C; the templating in VS makes it an easy setup and then no really specialist knowledge is needed to maintain and add new users

There isn't any special link between the two for now; both are in dev and the BS app just has a hard coded u/p for a single dev user inthe API side. At some point that needs to change so the API serves more than one customer via the UI

It seems I have a couple of routes I could go down:

- Make the BS app use the API for auth; in my mind this looks like setting up something similar to what you get when you make a new BS app with "Individual Accounts" auth, except it doesn't use EF on a database with tables for tracking identity - it would probably use a custom store and usermanager that asks the API for auth instead of some DB, and then some (hopefully simple) mechanism of getting the returned token from the API into every httpclient that ends up being used to poke the API (they're abstracted away into proxies built by NSwag but it's easy enough to address because NSwag code calls a particular overridable method to setup the headers.. finding a way to have the httpclientfactory do it might be even easier)
- Make the BS app and the API use AD B2C for auth. As a workflow I genuinely have no idea how that's done or what it looks like.

Of the two I'd prefer the latter because it hands off some additional responsibility to AD, such as maybe in future we want to have UI customers also do 2FA but I'm not really sure how to go about researching it. How do we go about sharing auth between the two systems?

I'm not looking for code; some rudimentary instructions on how to share the authenticated identity between the BS app and the API is really what I need. If it's not an achievable goal, what alternative mechanism for Blazor Server do I have that would allow easy sharing of a retrieved bearer across a everything the user might do in a "session" (I don't mind if they lose SignalR connection and have to log in again)?

If either of the approaches above look like I'm just making life hard work, and it should be done another way, an outline of the steps required to make it go would be ideal

Comment: _Make the BS app and the API use AD B2C for auth._ Tips: 1. Read doc about [oAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) 2. Read the doc about the [PKCE auth](https://oauth.net/2/pkce/) that is the flow you need. 3. Read the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application) about the OAuth implicit flow (obsolete) replaces by PKCE 4. Read Microsoft docs about [MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview) to obtain the token.